# iOS In-App Purchasing prevent charging 30% for subscription via website

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ios9, app-store-connect

I want to make a subscription to my app without using In App Purchase. Instead of it I want new user go to a web site from application and make a subscription with payment using few steps on web site.

Alos here are few steps how to implement it:

1. using UIWebView that will internally show subscription option from my site
2. using SFSafariViewController which also works without forcing leaving application.

Will Apple allow to do the subscription like this? Did someone face with the same situation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support question

Answer (score 3):

You can offer subscriptions through your website, but your application is not allowed to refer to that website or to try directing users to your website, or your app will be rejected.

Comment: so it means if I have web view with a page that contains a button "Subscribe" the apple will reject it, right?

Comment: or how for example Amazon do it?

Comment: This is not true for all cases. Only permitted for Reader app, see 3.1.3(a) of in-app purchase guidelines.Thats why spotify and netflix manage to do it but they fall under this category.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

> **11.12** Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP, Apple will share the same 70/30 revenue split with developers for these purchases, as set forth in the [Program License Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#agreements)

It's against the App Store Review Guidelines so your app will be rejected for trying to go around the IAP program.

Answer (score 0):

NO - You have to use In-app purchase.You can not use any of the work-around but it's depend on what types of apps you are developing. Using website (**previously purchased content**) is only possible for limited cases.It's only permitted for **Reader app, see 3.1.3(a)** of in-app purchase guidelines.That's why Spotify and Netflix manage to do it but they fall under this category.